# Logistic regression, where is my mistake

Tags: python, logistic-regression

I am doing assigment on Logistic Regression on Andrew Ng DL course, and can't understand where is my mistake,

```
# FORWARD PROPAGATION (FROM X TO COST)
### START CODE HERE ### (≈ 2 lines of code)
A = sigmoid(np.dot(w.T,X) + b)                       # compute activation
cost = -1/m * np.sum(np.dot(np.log(A), Y.T) + np.dot(np.log(1-A), (1-Y.T)))  # compute cost
```

### END CODE HERE ###

```
# BACKWARD PROPAGATION (TO FIND GRAD)
### START CODE HERE ### (≈ 2 lines of code)
dw = 1 / m *(np.dot(X,(A - Y).T))
db = 1 / m *(np.sum(A - Y))
### END CODE HERE ###

assert(dw.shape == w.shape)
assert(db.dtype == float)
cost = np.squeeze(cost)
assert(cost.shape == ())

grads = {"dw": dw,
         "db": db}

return grads, cost

w, b, X, Y = np.array([[1.],[2.]]), 2., np.array([[1.,2.,-1.],[3.,4.,-3.2]]), np.array([[1,0,1]])
grads, cost = propagate(w, b, X, Y)
print ("dw = " + str(grads["dw"]))
print ("db = " + str(grads["db"]))
print ("cost = " + str(cost))
```

Giving this error

```
ValueError: shapes (2,) and (3,1) not aligned: 2 (dim 0) != 3 (dim 0)
```

Please help 
Thanks a lot